# I want to modify multiple values at the same time in ldap. How can I do that?

Tags: python, ldap, ldap3

Hi guys I want to modify multiple values at the same. So here I want to modify the users UID Number but I have like 500 users and modifying it one at a time will take a lot of time. So how should I process it? For eg. I have 6 uid numbers here:

2147483739,
2147483740,
2147483741,
2147483742,
2147483743,
2147483744
I want to make these uid number shorter like 5000, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5005 how can I do that? How can I put multiple values at the same and modify it?

```
 conn.modify('uid=ac549027,ou=People,ou=Auth,o=CSUN', {'uidNumber': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['70100'])]})
```

Comment: Can you please explain more with proper examples.

Comment: Please check now I HAVE UPDATED THE QUESTION with an ex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP will only allow a modification on a single entry in one operation.

You would need to loop through the list of DNs you wish to modify and an perform a modification on each entry.